# How to correctly make nested directives work with jQuery Layout plugin and AngularJS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, layout, plugins, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to incorporate [jQuery Layout plugin](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/documentation.cfm) into my AngularJS project.

I have a working version that I built only using jQuery, jQuery-UI and jQuery Layout plugin [Here](http://achudars.github.io/resizable-layout-with-side-panels/)

Now I want to have the same thing in AngularJS.

I am particularly having trouble with passing default values to the nested instances of the plugin.

A simple example works like so:

**HTML:**

```html
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="outer-container" layout-container>
        <div class="ui-layout-west pane">WEST</div>
        <div class="ui-layout-center pane">MIDDLE</div>
        <div class="ui-layout-east pane">EAST</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('layoutContainer', function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var layout = element.layout({
                    west: {
                      resizable : true,
                      initClosed : false,
                      livePaneResizing: true,
                      size: 150
                    },
                    east: {
                      resizable : true,
                      initClosed : false,
                      livePaneResizing: true,
                      size: 150
                    }
                });
        }
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/achudars/a3SLn/)

The example I'm trying to replicate, however, doesn't work when I make it like so:

**HTML:**

```html
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="outer-container" layout-container>
        <div class="ui-layout-west pane">WEST</div>
        <div class="ui-layout-center pane">
            <div id="middle-container" layout-middle>
                <div class="ui-layout-north pane top-panel">
                    <div id="top-container" layout-top>
                        <div class="ui-layout-center pane">TOP LEFT</div>
                        <div class="ui-layout-east pane">TOP RIGHT</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-layout-center pane bottom-panel">
                    <div id="bottom-container" layout-bottom>
                        <div class="ui-layout-center pane">BOTTOM LEFT</div>
                        <div class="ui-layout-east pane">BOTTOM RIGHT</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-layout-east pane">EAST</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('layoutContainer', function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var layout = element.layout({
                    west: {
                      resizable : true,
                      initClosed : true,
                      livePaneResizing: true,
                      size: 350
                    },
                    east: {
                      resizable : true,
                      initClosed : true,
                      livePaneResizing: true,
                      size: 350
                    }
                });
        }
    }
});

app.directive('layoutMiddle', function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var layout = element.layout({
                    north: {
                          size: .5,
                          livePaneResizing: true
                        }
                });
        }
    }
});

app.directive('layoutTop', function() {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            angular.element(element).layout({
                east: {
                      size: .5,
                      livePaneResizing: true
                    }
            });
        }
    };
});

app.directive('layoutBottom', function() {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            angular.element(element).layout({
                east: {
                      size: .5
                    }
            });

        }
    };
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/achudars/X52vd/)

My goal is to make panels `TOP LEFT`, `TOP RIGHT`, `BOTTOM LEFT` and `BOTTOM RIGHT` take up all the space equally by default.

**EDIT**: the issue is in the fact that directives are compiled asynchronously. What is the correct AngularJS way to compile directives sequentially [in this case, layoutContainer must be first, then layoutMiddle and then the remaining layoutTop and layoutBottom]?

Answer (score 0):

Angular's directive compilation and linking is sequential, but its order is the reverse of what you're presuming.  Elements are compiled before their descendants and are linked before their ancestors.

One way to resolve this is to build a stack of deferred actions during `link()` and then emptying this stack in lifo order once the Container has had its turn.

Take a look at [this fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jheinnic/2ugPw/) for a demonstration and one possible resolution.  The differences that reverse the order of `element.layout()` calls are as follows:

1. Created a service called `lifoRunner` that has a `push()` method for building a stack of functions and a `runStack()` method that pops the stack and runs each method until the stack is empty.
2. Injected `lifoRunner` as dependency of each directive.
3. Migrated the body of each link function to a new function.  Instead of executing its former code, each `link()` method now passes its new encapsulating function to `lifoRunner.push()`.
4. The last directive to link, layoutContainer, additionally calls `lifoRunner.runStack()` immediately after it calls `lifoRunner.push()`.  The other three directive link methods only call `lifoRunner.push()`.

To further illustrate the point, I also added two calls to `console.log()` at the same relative positions of each directive.

- In the body of link() and before calling `lifoRunner.push()`, I `log("Link <DirectiveName>")`.
- At the first line of the function passed to `lifoRunner.push()`, I `log("Stack <DirectiveName>")`.

On loading the Fiddle, you'll see the cells are now sized as you expect, and you'll find the following in your console to establish the evaluation order:

```
Link Top
Link Bottom
Link Middle
Link Container
Stack Container
Stack Middle
Stack Bottom
Stack Top
```

Cheers!